# Pluggable appenders per dynamic logging category?

Tags: java, logging, dynamic, log4j, slf4j

I am using SLF4J and Log4J back-end.

I have stand-alone Java service, which takes "tasks" from queue and executes the tasks in separate threads *(Akka Actors, if that matters)*. I want to send log messages to per-task log files (so every task starts to log into it's own unique log file).

My requirements are:

- implicitly pass task ID with log message
- choose file to log by that ID
- remove the ID when task ends, so no subsequent tasks can log to wrong file by accident

So far it looks like I have to create my own log appender, which will "recognize" task by some criteria (this is a big question, since I don't see how to pass task ID to logger easily, and can not rely on ThreadLocal because some tasks may start thread pools/fork-join, so it would be complex to inherit thread context)

Do you know any existing logging implementation which might work for me? May be some extensions to Log4J?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a not-so-widely known feature of Log4J that may help you to acomplish the task. Own appender approach seems right and to pass an ID reliably you can use Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC). Somewhere, where the task ID is known, you can put task id into MDC:

```
MDC.put("id", id);
```

In your custom appender just fetch it back:

```
Object id = MDC.get("id");
```

The main advantage MDC can give you comparing to simple ThreadLocal storage is a kind of "thread inheritance". A child thread automatically inherits a copy of the mapped diagnostic context of its parent:

```
    MDC.put("id", "1");
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(MDC.get("id"));  // prints 1
        }
    }.start();
```

Having a task id in your custom appender you can forward the output to an appropriate file with ease. SLF4J also offers MDC, but it's behavior depends on the underlying implementation.